# What is the best flutter widget to use to achieve this kinda layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: UI for a user profile]

This is the UI I want to implement, I only started playing with flutter last week so I am not as fluent. I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this layout.

This is what I get with a stack and column:
[image]

This is the code:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 150),
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              bottom: -40,
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
              // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 80, width: 80),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      flex: 3,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      flex: 7,
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: I know a stack can be used with an overflow, but that feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: It shouldn't feel like a hack, because it isn't.

Comment: One issue I faced with a stack was that I couldn't prevent the white container where the text widget containing the name (David Beckham) and the model/super start from being expanded the full parent

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? There are more than one layout aspects in the picture.

Comment: whenever I use a combination of stack, containers and column I am not getting the desired result, the plus, profile and message icon either are displayed below the white background container or they don't overflow at all.

Comment: use a container then give the white color to the background for the child use Image then give the height of the image half of the context , use  row for the three widget and that is all of it

Comment: i forgot to write it you should do that inside a stack widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something like the image you provided with dummy image and some icon you can change icons if you want,use media query size instead of fixed padding tops

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: [
              Container(
                child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/300?image=10')),
                height: 150,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.message,
                        size: 27.0,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 55.0,
                        backgroundImage:
                            NetworkImage('https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=54'),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      Text("David Beckham"),
                      Text("Model/SuperStar")
                    ]),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        size: 27.0,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that more of what I am looking for, I wasn't aware that you could also use padding to position widget like in css..

Comment: There is something called `Positioned` check that also if you want https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html @jeffdropsit

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. It just that the content always overflow below the red widget in that example I posted.

Comment: ok,the code i provided there is no problem right,if it there let me know@jeffdropsit

Comment: Thanks for asking, I doubt the problem is with the code, but now that you mention itI am still struggling with getting a container to fill the white space there below the row widget. By that I mean as soon as I add a container below that row widget, it either hides the icons or messes up the view..

Comment: That almost does the trick,almost.  is it not possible to have the container with the mountain image touching the container with the red color?

Comment: The design you provided this code will be fine,but container under image It's kind tricky thing to do  @jeffdropsit

Comment: ya, I figured. Thanks a lot though. If I could upvote you twice I would.

Comment: ✌✌✌@jeffdropsit